# problem with circle correct eye detection in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I have a problem with correct eye detection in the program below. The problem is the detection of eyes in the wrong place. If anyone knows the answer please help

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()  

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)  
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 5)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + w, x:x + w]  
        roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]  
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.3, 5)  
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
           # center_coordinates = ex + ew // 2, ey + eh // 2
            radius = eh // 2
            cv2.circle(roi_color, (ex, ey), radius, (0, 0, 255), 5)
         #cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 5)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Did you intend to use `y+w`  in `roi_gray = gray[y:y + w, x:x + w] ` or did you mean to have `y+h` in `roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]`

Comment: I fixed it but it didn't help my problem :(

Answer (score 1):

When you draw a rectangle with `cv2.rectangle` you need top-left and bottom-right corners but when you draw a circle with `cv2.circle` you need the centre point. You are using `cv2.circle` with the same coordinates as with the initial rectangles, you need to transform them to the centre before. Add this and it should work

```
for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
    radius = eh//2
    eye_x = int(ex+0.5*ew)
    eye_y = int(ey+0.5*ey)
    cv2.circle(roi_color, (eye_x, eye_y), radius, (0, 0, 255), 5)
```

Comment: Thank you so much <3